# post-receive hook with deploy commands not working properly

Tags: git, bash, version-control, hook

I have a git on a remote, and have added a post-receive hook. The post-receive hook should do the following.

If `[composer]` is present in the commit message, do a composer update
If `[deploy]` is present in the commit message, checkout the branch that has been pushed (e.g. `feature/test`, `master`, etc.)
If `[migrate]` is present in the commit message, do a `php artisan migrate`

Unfortunetely, this doesn't work. The hook is called, but the actions are "wrong".

This is the script

```
#!/bin/sh
MESSAGE=$(git log -1 HEAD --pretty=format:%s)

if [[ "$MESSAGE" == *\[composer\]* ]]; then
    composer --working-dir=/var/www/feedev/ update
fi

if [[ "$MESSAGE" == *\[deploy\]* ]]; then
    while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`
    git --work-tree=/var/www/feeddev/ --git-dir=/home/feeddev/staging.git checkout -f $branch
done
else
    git --work-tree=/var/www/feedev/ --git-dir=/home/feeddev/staging.git checkout -f
fi

if [[ "$MESSAGE" == *\[migrate\]* ]]; then
    php /var/www/feedev/artisan migrate
fi
```

---

This isn't working, because, for testing purposes, I added those lines

```
touch /home/ezidev/ezidev.git/$MESSAGE.lock
```

after the message variable is read, and also if, the second case is false, add this

```
touch /home/ezidev/ezidev.git/nodeploy.lock
```

So now I'm commiting, and have the commit message [deploy], but, no new branch is checked out, and also two new files are generated

`touch /home/ezidev/ezidev.git/$MESSAGE.lock` generates `/home/ezidev/ezidev.git/static.lock`

and

`touch /home/ezidev/ezidev.git/nodeploy.lock` generates `/home/ezidev/ezidev.git/nodeploy.lock`

Why is the $MESSAGE = static.lock? I didn't write this into my commit messages. What could be the problem, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Do your git remote user have correct privileges?

Comment: Which do I need? I think I got the correct one, since it's creating the files, or do you mean sth. else?

Comment: Do you need the `--work-tree` and/or `--git-dir` arguments on the `git log` call too?

Comment: I looked at the documentation: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log but there aren't parameters for log which are work-tree and/or git-dir unfortunetely

Comment: @Musterknabe: `git log` doesn't examine the work tree so it does not need `--work-tree`.  It does examine the git directory, and does take `--git-dir` (the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` flags are handled by the `git` front-end command, not the back-end `log` or `checkout`, so all commands accept them) but you don't need to set anything here anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a post-receive hook is run after git has collected new objects and updated some reference(s), such as `refs/heads/master`, `refs/heads/bra/nch`, and/or `refs/tags/v1.3`.  ("References" are the general name of branches, tags, the special stash reference, and so on.  The two that are *normally* updated on a "receive" operation are branches and tags, with the tag update *normally* just being the creation of a new tag.  Other updates are possible, though, depending on what you allow in your pre-receive and update hooks.  Also, if you use git's "notes" you will see names beginning with `refs/notes/`.)

With that in mind, let's look at the very first command in your script:

```
MESSAGE=$(git log -1 HEAD --pretty=format:%s)
```

This uses `HEAD`.  What commit(s) does `HEAD` refer to?

This is not just a rhetorical question.  The `HEAD` reference is normally an indirect reference to a branch: it specifies which branch the repository is "on", in terms of the current check-out.  Running `git checkout $branch` changes the contents of `HEAD`.  This is true even in a bare repository: `HEAD` refers to some branch, initially `master` but changeable, and in your case likely to change since there are some `git checkout` commands in the script.

There's no way for me to know what was in `HEAD` at the time your script ran (and in general, if the script ran it may have changed `HEAD`, so it may be difficult or even impossible for you to find out).  But that would determine which commit `git log` examined: `HEAD` will likely contain a branch name, and the branch name will indicate one specific commit, and that will be the (single) commit that `git log` uses.

Now let's go back to what a post-receive hook actually gets, again.  It's run *after* receiving some objects (perhaps even thousands of commits) and updating some references (perhaps even dozens of references).  You are then looking at *one* commit on *one* branch, which may or may not be one of perhaps many that were updated, and using that to decide how to handle *all* the updates of perhaps many commits on many branches.

This seems unlikely to be correct.

I can't really write your hook for you, but let's take one more look at part of what you already have, which has some correct code within it (and some iffy-at-best code too):

```
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`
    git --work-tree=/var/www/feeddev/ --git-dir=/home/feeddev/staging.git checkout -f $branch
done
```

The post-receive hook is told which references were updated, and in what fashion, as a set of lines on the standard input.  This `while` loop reads those lines.  That means the `while` part is correct.

The first command *within* the loop is at least somewhat broken, though.  After reading a line from stdin, `$ref` will be something like `refs/heads/master`, `refs/heads/bra/nch`, and `refs/tags/v1.3`.  The echo-and-cut sequence simply takes the third word of each: `master`, `bra`, and `v1.3`.  The first is OK: it's the short form of the full name `refs/heads/master`, i.e., branch `master`.  The second is not OK: it's part of the short form of branch `bra/nch`, but it's only *part* of it, and it won't work well.  The third is also probably not OK: it's the short form of the name `refs/tags/v1.3`, i.e., tag `v1.3`, but *it's a tag, not a branch*.  It seems likely that something different is appropriate for this.

Next, the script ignores both `$oldrev` and `$newrev` after reading them.  This works for most, but not all, post-receive actions: if `$ref` already exists, `$oldrev` is the SHA-1 it used to point-to, and `$newrev` is the SHA-1 it now points-to after the updates.  For instance, if you've just pushed some new commit(s) to branch `feat/ure` so that the branch is updated in fast-forward fashion, `$ref` is `refs/heads/feat/ure` and using `git rev-list $oldrev..$newrev` will get you the SHA-1s for each of the new commits.  (If it was a force push—e.g., `git push -f` or `git push +sha1:refs/heads/feat/ure` on the client—some commit(s) may be "taken away", and you can find them with `git rev-list $newrev..$oldrev`.)

But there are two more cases to consider: first, that `$ref` was just created.  This is the normal case for tags, since tags should normally never be changed, only created.  In this case `$oldrev` will be all-zeros (forty `0` characters).  It is in the general case impossible to find which commit(s), if any, are on *only* this reference (though there are some tricks one can use, e.g., add a *pre*-receive hook to prohibit updates that are impossible to figure out, so that you're left with only the handle-able special cases).  The last case is that `$ref` is being *deleted*, e.g., someone ran `git push origin :bra/nch` to delete `refs/heads/bra/nch` from the bare repository on the server.  In this case `$oldrev` will tell you what SHA-1 `refs/heads/bra/nch` was, and `$newrev` will be the special 40 `0`s "null SHA-1".  You won't be able to check out that branch since it was just deleted.

Finally, there's a `git checkout -f` that specifies a particular work-tree and git directory (the latter overrides the `$GIT_DIR` that is set in a post-receive hook).  These are probably correct paths, but `$branch` might not be a branch name: in our example cases here, it's `master`, then `bra`, then `v1.3` in turn, on each of the three trips through the `while` loop.

---

In short (I know, "too late" :-) ) this particular post-receive hook is pretty badly flawed.  You'll need to figure out what cases you really want to handle, and write a new one that starts by running the `while` loop:

```
while read oldrev newrev ref; do
    ...
done
```

Inside the loop, inspect *all three* variables.  Check `$oldrev` and `$newrev` against the 40-`0`s null-SHA1 to determine whether the operation is a creation, deletion, or update.  Then check the first components of `$ref` to find the ref's name-space; if it's a branch, starting with `refs/heads/`, you can then strip off the `refs/heads/` part to get the branch name; if it's something else, you can perhaps just `continue` the loop to ignore the change.

If you're going to use `cut` to strip off `refs/heads/`, be sure to use `-f3-` and not just `-f3`.  (I prefer to use the shell's built-in ability to strip strings, `${ref#refs/heads/}` myself, but `echo ${ref} | cut -d/ -f3-` does work.)

Then, if it's a branch update (not a creation, not a deletion, just an update), you can use `git rev-list $oldrev..$newrev` to find commit(s) added to that branch.  Use `git log` on each one (or for efficiency, `git log $oldrev..$newrev`—`git log` will run `git rev-list` for you) to inspect their commit subject lines and/or commit message bodies for keywords.  Act appropriately, whatever "appropriate" is, on the commit(s) and/or branch based on the (perhaps multiple) keywords given in each commit.

Comment: Your comment helped me pretty much. When using `git log -1 HEAD --pretty=format:%s` I can see that it gets the last commit message of the branch it's currently on. So I push develop, but the message that it's received is from `master`. This is the first step in the right direction. If I see something more, I'll messag eyou

Comment: You're still missing a key point: a single `git push` can push to two branches, or three branches, or four or five or more.  The post-receive hook gets *all* these updates, so you must check all of them and base your action or actions on possibly many branch, tag, or other updates.

Comment: I understand this concern, however, currently the use case that we are pushing multiple branches at once doesn't exist. If we want a specific feature online, we push that branch. If we want to see multiple features at once, we got a temp branch. So another branch that gets single pushed. We are using SourceTree, so pushing multiple branches at once "shouldn't" happen

Comment: You can guarantee that it can't happen by including a pre-receive hook that rejects incoming updates if there are multiple branches in them (or any other conditions you wish to require).  However, this is usually the wrong approach: usually the right approach is simply to handle them.  Loop, reading all the updates; if branch A is updated, check the new commits on A; then if branch B is updated, check those commits; and so on.